# MS Access table source

Tags: ms-access

(Access 2003)
I have a single user form that has been designed with no associated table. It's sole purpose is to collect user entered criteria then perform a database search.

I have recently added a save facility so that separate search criterias can be held in an accompanying save table. The intention is to allow users the ability to save a new criteria, delete an existing one, navigate to previous criteria saves, edit previous saves. The criterias can be quite extensive and there is a requirement to run /edit-run the same criterias at a later date as the database grows. so this is a handy feature.

Problem:
While I am able to set the control source of e.g. a combobox to the savetable, I can't get record navigation to work..."DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext" fails.

I think this problem is due to the user form not being linked in some way to this new savetable.

Comment: Have you considered a subform for the savetable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll look into doing this.

Comment: Simply, you have an unbound form where the `RecordSource` is bank. Just bound the form to the savetable and navigation, search/filters, save/delete controls should work since now there is underlying data.

Comment: @Parfait probably not a good idea.

Comment: So @Fionnuala the default setting of an MS Access form is not a good idea? As the OP said: "the intention is to allow users the ability to save a new criteria, delete an existing one, navigate to previous criteria saves, edit previous saves." Unless I am missing something obvious, this is the standard functionality of a bound MS Access form.